# Efficiency of lots of inotify watches or stat calls

Tags: stat, inotify, efficiency

I am developing software that will utilize inotify to track changes on a large amount of files (tens to hundreds of thousands of files). I have come up with these ideas:

- one watch per file
- one watch per parent directory
- avoid inotify and periodically scan the fs for changes (not preferred)

I will have a database of all of the files I am watching and some basic stat information (like mtime and size), however, I would have to stat each file in that directory until I found the one that changed.

**Which would be faster, tons (100,000+) of inotify watches or tons of stat calls?**

I'm thinking that reducing the number of stat calls would be better, but I don't know enough about inotify.

Note:

This will be running on a workstation, not a server. It's main purpose is to synchronize changes (potentially to an entire filesystem) between a client and a remote server.

Comment: There are filesystems designed for this kind of replication. I recommend investigating them rather than reinventing the locomotive (it's more complex than a wheel). I don't have a filesystem to offer but I remember one being mentioned on this site recently, hopefully someone can chime in with proposals.

Comment: I would be very interested. The only thing I can think of is an NFS filesystem, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, found it: [ChironFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiron_FS). Even if you don't end up using it, its design documentation and source code are likely to be interesting reads.

Comment: @Gilles- Thanks. I assumed it would be a FUSE-based fs. I'll probably end up needing more features than it has, and it looks a little too young, but definitely an interesting read.

Comment: Using a filesystem based on this is not the way to go. This would be for servers where you have admins. This mentality is what makes Linux still in the 1% marketshare. This functionality should be able to be used with a quickly installed flatpak/snap after a download. This comment is for left here for eternity as a reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `read()` an inotify fd, the `name` field of the returned struct tells you which file was modified relative to the directory being watched, so you shouldn't have to stat every file in a directory after the event.

See http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Specifically:

> ```
> struct inotify_event {
>     int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
>     uint32_t mask;     /* Mask of events */
>     uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related
>                           events (for rename(2)) */
>     uint32_t len;      /* Size of 'name' field */
>     char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
> };
> ```
>
> The name field is only present when an event is returned for a file
>   inside a watched directory; it identifies the file pathname relative
>   to the watched directory. This pathname is null-terminated, and may
>   include further null bytes to align subsequent reads to a suitable
>   address boundary.

Comment: So, is there any gain to adding a listener to individual files?

Comment: Only if there are going to be many events on files you don't care about in that directory.

Comment: WARNING. THIS WILL NOT WORK.  Just imagine hard links. The kernel does not maintain a hardlink database. It might only report for modifications if the user is opening the file via the same file path. So a general purpose watcher still has to scan peridocially unless newer APIs like fannotify will be provided by the kernel.